# Change div size on hover over <li>

Tags: html, css

Good morning everybody.
I'm creating a website and I can't understand if it's possible to change a div size simply on hover over a "li".
In this page I have a menu with different elements and I'd like to resize the transparent box depending on the element selected. For example, I'd like to mantain the same dimension for all the elements except for the last (blue), that increase the box dimension from 250px to 350px.
This is the main HTML code:
...

```
<div class="menu_main">
            <ul class="menu slide">
            <li><a href="...." class="orange">NAME2</a></li>
            <li><a href="...." class="blue">NAME1</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
```

...

And the CSS code is:

.....

```
.menu_main {
    float:left;
    font:normal bold 11px/35px verdana, sans-serif;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    left:50px;
}


.menu_main .box {
    -moz-transition-duration:.4s;
    -o-transition-duration:.4s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:.4s;
    background-color:rgba(255, 250, 250, 0.5);
    height:0;
    width:900px;
}
.menu_main:hover div.box {
    height:250px;
}
```

....

```
.ul.menu li a.blue:hover,ul.menu li:hover a.blue {
    background:#c00;
```

}

....

Thank you very much for your attention. I hope I have been clear

Comment: Hello, first I suggest you to learn about [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if you want more help from the StackOverflow community. You'll love this

Comment: you can't change the style of an element on hover of a different element. You will need to glue this behaviour thru a little of javascript code.

Comment: It looks like what you have is working. Put a border around your "box" div and watch its height change when you hover on "menu_main". With it "transparent" you can't tell that it changes. http://jsfiddle.net/xLtdr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest including jQuery in your head section using `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>` which will allow you to use the following code to achieve what you want to do:

```
$('.blue').hover(function() {
$('.box').css(width: '350px');},
function() {
$('.box').css(width: '250px');};);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.main_menu:hover .blue {
    width: 350px;
    transition: width 1s;
}
```

Comment: Sure, I tried but it doesn't change the "box" size but the <li> one !!

Comment: That's what you asked for.  To change the size of box, replace .blue for .box